# Why do these two inputs result in different outputs?

Tags: ruby, debugging, recursion

So I have the following Ruby script:

```
def f( a , b , c )
  if b < 0
    p = q = 1
    if c[ 0 ] < 0
      while p != 0
        if p == c.length
          p = 0
          return a + 1
        elsif c[ p ] < 0
          p += 1
        else
          c[ p ] -= 1
          c[ p - 1 ] = a
          p = 0
          return f( a , b , c )
        end
      end
    else
      c[ 0 ] -= 1
      return f( a , a , c )
    end
  else
    return f( f( a , -1 , c ) , b-1 , c )
  end
end

#Why do the below two return different numbers?
f( 2 , 0 , [ 0 , -1 ] )
f( f( 2 , -1 , [ 0 , -1 ] ) , -1 , [ 0 , -1 ] )
```

They are supposed to return the same thing.  Since the first one has a second argument greater than or equal to zero, we should have it run to the last `else` case and return `f(f(2,-1,[0,1]),-1,[0,1])`, but when I run the two, they do not return the same results.

https://repl.it/GvD3/10

According to the above link, we have

```
f(2,0,[0,-1]) = 7
f(f(2,-1,[0,-1]),-1,[0,-1]) = 14
```

and I can't figure out what I've done wrong here.  (if you can fix this, thanks as well)

---

The function should look something like the following for an array `c` of length four:

https://repl.it/GvD3/17

---

Some examples to show how this is supposed to work:

```
  f(3,1,[2,3])
= f(f(3,-1,[2,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(3,3,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(3,-1,[1,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(3,3,[0,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(f(3,-1,[0,3]),2,[0,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(f(3,3,[-1,3]),2,[0,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(f(f(3,-1,[-1,3]),2,[-1,3]),2,[0,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(f(f(3,-1,[3,2]),2,[-1,3]),2,[0,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
= f(f(f(f(f(3,3,[2,2]),2,[-1,3]),2,[0,3]),2,[1,3]),0,[2,3])
```

And now I'm going to be honest and tell you that `f(3,1,[2,3])` is much larger than anything you would normally deal with.  Indeed, the program I am making will almost always return `stack level too deep`, for the amount of stacks I am running through are sheer insanity.  I'm supposed to run this on a theoretical computer with infinite resources and the like, and I'm trying to recreate a version of [FAIL](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Simply_Beautiful_Art/Fast_Array_Iteration_Leaping) with no @ symbols.

The general explanation of this in words:

If `b>-1`, then we do `b+1` nestings of the function inside the first argument:

`f(a,3,c) = f(f(f(f(a,-1,c),-1,c),-1,c),-1,c)`

If `b=-1` but the first element of `c0=-1`, then replace the second argument with the first argument.

`f(a,-1,[c0, c1, ...]) = f(a,a,[c0 - 1, c1, ...])`

Else, if the second element is `-1`, then replace the first element with the first argument, else, if the third element is `-1`, then replace the second element with the first argument etc.

If the second argument and all of the elements of the array are `-1`, then we have

`f(a,-1,c) = a + 1`

---

More intuitively, we have: (not real equalities)

```
f(a,-1,[-1,-1,-1, ...]) = addition
f(a,-1,[ 0,-1,-1, ...]) = repeated addition = multiplication
f(a,-1,[ 1,-1,-1, ...]) = repeated multiplication = exponentiation
f(a,-1,[ 2,-1,-1, ...]) = repeated exponentiation = tetration
...
f(a,-1,[-1, 0,-1, ...]) = Ackermann function (it climbs up the previous functions)
f(a,-1,[ 0, 0,-1, ...]) = repeated Ackermann functions
f(a,-1,[ 1, 0,-1, ...]) = repeated previous function nested into itself
f(a,-1,[ 2, 0,-1, ...]) = repeated previous function nested into itself
...
f(a,-1,[-1, 1,-1, ...]) = some function that climbs up through the list of previous functions
...
f(a,-1,[-1,-1, 0, ...]) = some function that climbs through functions of the form f(a,-1,[-1, k,-1, ...])
f(a,-1,[ 0,-1, 0, ...]) = repeated nesting of the previous function
f(a,-1,[-1, 0, 0, ...]) = some function that climbs through function of the form f(a,-1,[ k,-1, 0, ...])
f(a,-1,[ 0,-1, 1, ...]) = some function that climbs through functions of the form f(a,-1,[ 0, k, 0, ...])
```

And I hope you get the general idea.

[Ackermann function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AckermannFunction.html)

Comment: Embedded spaces around operators and in parameter definitions are a really good idea. Ruby isn't C or Perl.

Comment: @theTinMan Like that?  It doesn't seem to make an apparent difference though :-(

Comment: Do you mean `if p = c.length` (to assign then compare) or `if p == c.length` (only compare)? The first is a very common error, though it's legitimate code. We don't deliberately do it in Ruby because it's difficult to tell if it's something desired when debugging.

Comment: @theTinMan Oh, that's right.  Though it doesn't seem to affect my function :-/

Comment: I'm curious what's causing the bug, as when I replace `c` with a constant and change my code to treat it like an array of length one, it works fine... https://repl.it/GvD3/12

Comment: Oops, fixed.  https://repl.it/GvD3/13

Comment: The name of this method and the arguments makes understanding this code extremely frustrating. It'd much better if you explain what this is supposed to do, especially through clarity of code and examples of desired and actual output.

Comment: @tadman Have you taken a look at the very last link of my question?  And thanks for the suggestions, I'll take them and add in some examples.

Comment: The links just give errors. It's almost always better to avoid external links except if there's no alternative and try and make your question as self-contained as possible. Services like that go down all the time.

Comment: @tadman If you wish, you could try smaller inputs into the given link.  And while I'm typing up the examples, you could also read this: [FAIL](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Simply_Beautiful_Art/Fast_Array_Iteration_Leaping) which is basically what I'm trying to recreate (without any @'s)

Comment: That's an odd article, but given the problem I'm surprised this isn't done with strings or an array of symbols to manipulate.

Comment: @tadman I'm more of a mathematician, so my coding experience is very limited to a few things I've needed to do... if you have any suggestions I'm open.  I also added an example while I was at it.

Comment: I think that link you have is really ineffective at explaining the fundamental problem you're trying to solve. I can't see any correlation between that FAIL link and this code. If you can explain better more people would be able to lend a hand or advise.

Comment: @tadman Well it was more of a side note... each element in the array is approximately equivalent to a # followed by the element in FAIL.  And I do hope the examples are enlightening?

Comment: @tadman I added a lot of context, explaining the basics as to how this function behaves in general in words as well as how the function compares to common operations.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are **modifying elements of the array `c`** inside the function calls. When the function returns, **`c`** is the modified one, not the original one. The new **`c`** is used in the subsequent function calls, resulting in the behavior you're getting.

### Edit

Here is an explanation of how **`f(2,0,[0,-1])`** is evaluated:

- The function call does not satisfy the condition **`b < 0`**, so it will go to the last `else` statement and execute `f( f(a ,-1 ,c), b-1, c)`
- The inner call is `f(a,-1,c)` which is `f(2, -1, [0,-1])`. This will return the value **`6`**. Also, during this evaluation, it will modify **`c`** into `[-1,-1]`.
- The outer call is now `f(6,b-1,c)`, which is `f(6, -1,`**`[-1,-1]`**`)`. Notice that `c` is **not** `[0,-1]` anymore. This will evaluate to **`7`**.

Hence, the equivalent call should be: **`f(f(2,-1,[0,-1]),-1,[-1,-1])`**, which will give the same result, **`7`**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I **want** it to modify `c` as it goes along... else the function would never terminate...

Comment: Ah, thank you!  That really explains.  I'll see if I can fix it based on that.

Comment: I tried to fix it but it still doesn't work :-( https://repl.it/GvD3/18  Any suggestions on how to fix this would be nice.

Comment: Hm, I honestly don't know how to work with variables like this yet... :-( This really sucks... XD